# How to sort most correlated variables and describe top 10 variables in pandas after finding correlation between columns

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have found correlations already between specified columns of full dataset:

```
var_0_to_var_9 = train_df.loc[:, 'var_0':'var_9']

correlation = var_0_to_var_9.corr(method = 'pearson')

print(correlation)
```

And I get such a correlation matrix:

```
          var_0     var_1     var_2     var_3     var_4     var_5     var_6  \
var_0  1.000000 -0.000544  0.006573  0.003801  0.001326  0.003046  0.006983   
var_1 -0.000544  1.000000  0.003980  0.000010  0.000303 -0.000902  0.003258   
var_2  0.006573  0.003980  1.000000  0.001001  0.000723  0.001569  0.000883   
var_3  0.003801  0.000010  0.001001  1.000000 -0.000322  0.003253 -0.000774   
var_4  0.001326  0.000303  0.000723 -0.000322  1.000000 -0.001368  0.000049   
var_5  0.003046 -0.000902  0.001569  0.003253 -0.001368  1.000000  0.002588   
var_6  0.006983  0.003258  0.000883 -0.000774  0.000049  0.002588  1.000000   
var_7  0.002429  0.001511 -0.000991  0.002500  0.004549 -0.000995 -0.002548   
var_8  0.004962  0.004098  0.002648  0.003553  0.001194  0.000147 -0.001188   
var_9 -0.002613 -0.000832 -0.001932 -0.000826 -0.000918 -0.005279 -0.005697   

          var_7     var_8     var_9  
var_0  0.002429  0.004962 -0.002613  
var_1  0.001511  0.004098 -0.000832  
var_2 -0.000991  0.002648 -0.001932  
var_3  0.002500  0.003553 -0.000826  
var_4  0.004549  0.001194 -0.000918  
var_5 -0.000995  0.000147 -0.005279  
var_6 -0.002548 -0.001188 -0.005697  
var_7  1.000000  0.000814  0.002885  
var_8  0.000814  1.000000 -0.001073  
var_9  0.002885 -0.001073  1.000000
```

Now, I would like to get top 10 most correlated variables from the given correlation matrix.

Is there anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as follows:

- Turn the lower (or upper) triangle plus diagonal into `NaN` values. We can use [`np.tril`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html) for this in combination with [`np.ones`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html) as `booleans` (i.e. `True`) and place the result, preceded by the unary operator (`~`), in [`df.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html).
- Next, use [`df.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to turn the `df` into a `Series` and apply [`Series.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

largest_10 = correlation.where(~np.tril(np.ones(
    correlation.shape, dtype=bool))).stack().nlargest(10)

print(largest_10)

var_0  var_6    0.006983
       var_2    0.006573
       var_8    0.004962
var_4  var_7    0.004549
var_1  var_8    0.004098
       var_2    0.003980
var_0  var_3    0.003801
var_3  var_8    0.003553
var_1  var_6    0.003258
var_3  var_5    0.003253
dtype: float64
```

Here, the index of `largest_10` corresponds to `x, y`. E.g. you can access the values inside the `df` as follows:

```
print(correlation.loc[largest_10.index[0]])
0.006983

# e.g., equivalent to `print(correlation.loc['var_0','var_6'])`
```